# How to search for hotels with a genuine in-room spa bath?

Tags: usa, online-resources, accommodation-search-engines

When using sites like Kayak to search for hotels with spa baths, they typically return hotels that have public spa baths co-located with their public pools.  But what I want to find are hotels that have private spa baths in their rooms.

Are there any websites that allow to filter for that feature?  And/Or are there any tricks that I am overlooking when doing searches?

FWIW I'm currently only interested in hotels in the US.